# How to interpolate in pandas using multiple neigbouring points?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

If I use `df.interpolate` with `linear` it draws straight lines between the last and first point. I see the options for `spline` or `polynominal`, but can you make it consider several neighbours using a linear regression?

Example:

```
     A    B
0  1.0  0.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  5.0  4.0
5  6.0  10.0
6  7.0  12.0
7  8.0  14.0
8  9.0  16.0
```

Now `df.interpolate(method='linear')` will result in 3 for both columns. That's essentially using the formula `ax+b`, and will also work if we have several rows missing. However, I want to fit `ax+b` with multiple rows/points.

I can do this with scipy, but was hoping that pandas could do the same as it does offer more intricate interpolation as well.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np 

def lin_reg(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b


(a, b), _ = curve_fit(
    lin_reg, 
    [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
    [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
    (2, 0)
)

print(lin_reg(np.array([2, 3]), a, b))  # just 3, 4 
      
(a, b), _ = curve_fit(
    lin_reg, 
    [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
    [0, 2, 4, 10, 12, 14, 16], 
    (2, 0)
)

print(lin_reg(np.array([2, 3]), a, b))  # 3.3, 5.4
```

Answer (score 0):

With a straight line, no. There is just one way to draw a straight line between two points.

Otherwise, yes you can. The question is how would you want it to?

If you consider:

```
     A    B
0  1.0  0.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  4.0  4.0
4  5.0  4.5
```

For which the default [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) gives the same value:

```
df.interpolate()

     A    B
0  1.0  0.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  3.0  # only considering n-1/n+1
3  4.0  4.0
4  5.0  4.5
```

You can use a polynomial, or spline interpolation:

```
df.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2)

     A     B
0  1.0  0.00
1  2.0  2.00
2  3.0  3.25  # considering the neighbors
3  4.0  4.00
4  5.0  4.50
```

Visual output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I changed my question to make it more clear :)

Comment: @Roelant it's still unclear, can you provide an exact calculation? Or at least logic? How would you do it with pen and paper?

Comment: added scipy code I would use. Hope it's more clear now :)

Comment: so what happens if you have several NaNs in a column? Do they all match the same fit?

Comment: They get interpolated with the linear regression? Extended my example to a gap of 2 NaNs.

Comment: I meant disjoint, like `[1, 2, NaN, 3, 4, NaN, 7]`